# LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Board_Game, expected /models/board_game.rb to define it)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Full server error:

`LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Board_Game, expected /Users/michellegarcia/coding_personal_projects/board_game_app/app/models/board_game.rb to define it):`

`` app/controllers/api/board_games_controller.rb:3:in `index' ``

I have a spelling or capitalization mistake here, but I can't find where. I want to console.log all `Board_Games` that I have manually seeded into my database so that I list them.

#### controller

```
class Api::BoardGamesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render json: Board_Game.all
  end

  def show
    render json: @board_games
  end

  def create
    board_game = Board_Game.new 
    if board_game.save
      render json: board_game 
    else
      render json: board_game.errors
    end 
  end

  def update
    if @board_game.update(board_game_params)
      render json: @board_game 
    else 
      render_error(@board_game)
    end 
  end

  def destroy 
    @board_game.destroy 
  end 

  private 

  # def set_board_game 
  #   @board_game = Board_Game.find(params[:id])
  # end 

  def board_game_params
    params.require(:board_game).permit(
    :title,
    :min_players,
    :max_players,
    :base_game,
    :time_needed,
    :company 
    )
  end 

end
```

#### model

```
class BoardGame < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :game_sessions, through: :game_session_games 
  has_many :rounds 
end
```

#### routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'api/auth'
  namespace :api do
    resources :board_games do 
      resources :game_sessions 
    end 
    #API ROUTES SHOULD GO HERE
  end

  #Do not place any routes below this one
  get '*other', to: 'static#index'
end
```

#### board game component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; 

//needs to do a call to the API to get the user's games from the user_board_game table 
//if the user has no games, it needs to default to "You have no games. Add games to your library by clicking
//"Add Game""
//don't know if "Add Game" should be its own component or a conditional render. 
//I want people to be able to add multiple games at once. Search Games. And have the option to add a game
//not on the list and auto-add it to their library. Also should have a checkbox for 
//"I have played this game before" so their backlog can be easily sorted. 
//if they've clicked on Add a Game, it should no longer render in the other component

class Games extends Component {

  state = { games:[] }
//wasn't hitting debugger in componentDidMount because I had Component capitalized. 
//then I was getting a 500 from my server because I didn't have resources :board_games in my routes.rb
//now getting 404
//this error "ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api)" in server 
//created an api folder in my controllers folder and moved my proprietery controllers inside it
//new error: app/controllers/api/board_games_controller.rb:15: 
//syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting keyword_end
//got rid of 422 on line 15 
//new error: LoadError (Unable to autoload constant 
//Api::BoardGamesController, expected 
///Users/michellegarcia/coding_personal_projects/board_game_app/app/controllers/api/board_games_controller.rb
// to define it):
// my has_many :blank didn't have colons in board_game.rb 
  componentDidMount() {
//runs when the user wants to add a game from the database
//link to more info and button to add the game if it's not in their library already 
    axios.get('/api/board_games')
      .then(res => {
        // const games = res.data;
        console.log(res); 
        // this.setState({games});
      })
  }

  getUserGames = () => {
//runs when component mounts and then goes to the Games_List Function
//checks if the user has games user.games? return { the list} : return {<h1>You have no games</h1>}
  }

  gamesList = () => {
//gives each game with a link to more info  
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Games</h1>
        <button>Add a Game</button> 
        <h3>Your Games</h3> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Games;
```

I've left all of my dumb notes and undefined logic in the app in case you can foresee a problem coming or have any other notes. I'm just here to learn so I'm open to critiques on anything.

Most other posts here that have a similar title seem to have issues with the same class name in different namespaces, which I don't have yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `Board_Game.all` and `Board_Game.new` in your controller, your class is `BoardGame` (without the `_`)

Comment: Thought it might be something like that. Thank you! That's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the page of your Controller, and compare the file name with `class nameFile <ApplicationController`. That name must be the same.